# How do I replace all of one character string in one column with another column's character string in the same row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
sample   tissue   disease
s1       brain    glioblastoma
s2       skin     melanoma
s3       liver    NA
s4       kidney   carcinoma
s5       nerve    NA
```

How would I go about replacing all NAs with "Normal [corresponding tissue]"? E.g., for sample 3, NA would be replaced with "liver normal" and for sample 5 NA would be replaced with "nerve normal".

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical vector based on the NA occurrence in 'disease' and then `paste` the corresponding 'tissue' elements with 'normal' to update the 'disease' column

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$disease)
df1$disease[i1] <- paste(df1$tissue[i1], "normal")
```

---

Or more concisely in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[is.na(disease), disease := paste0(tissue, 'normal')]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to figure out how to reference other columns in R like this, but this was exactly what I needed! I appreciate the help!!

Comment: @avery For extracting a column, you can use `$` or `[` or `[[` i.e. `df$disease` or `df[, "disease"]` or `df[["disease"]]`.  I would use `[[` to avoid any surprises (as `$` can have some partial match issues and would not work if you are trying to call from an object or in a loop i.e. `for(nm in names(df1)) print(df1[[nm]])` works